# Captivate 7 - Hide 'next' button until q‌u‌e‌s‌t‌i‌o‌n is answered

Tags: adobe-captivate

We're trying to make it compulsory to answer a question before advancing to the next slide.
Ideally we want to hide / remove the next navigation button until the question is answered.

P.S. I did check the Adobe forums and it suggested putting the next button under the clear button - which works....but not if you navigate back to the slide - you cannot go forward then.